# how to call async method in MainPage

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{    
    public  MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I want to call here:

```
var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to call this in the OnAppearing() method and specifically in the contructor, you can do this (watch out for possible thread blocking though):

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // watch out for possible thread blocking!
            Task.Run(async() =>
            {
                await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: OR if you need to be on MainThread: `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() => ...`.

Answer (score 2):

call it in `OnAppearing`

```
public override async void OnAppearing()
{
    var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
}
```